# java.lang.NullPointerException while running apache mahout FP growth in Eclipse

Tags: apache, mahout

I'm new to apache mahout. I'm trying out FP growth algorithm of Apache Mahout to run it from java. Here is the code I use,

```
FPGrowth<String> fp = new FPGrowth<String>(); 
FileLineIterable file = new FileLineIterable(new File(FPInputFileName)); 
int minSupport = 2;
int maxHeapSize = 50;
Writer writer = null;
StringOutputConverter output = new StringOutputConverter(new SequenceFileOutputCollector<Text,TopKStringPatterns>(writer));
String pattern = " "; //currently understood as splitter
try{
        fp.generateTopKFrequentPatterns(new StringRecordIterator(file,pattern), fp.generateFList(new StringRecordIterator(file, pattern), minSupport), minSupport, maxHeapSize, null, output, null);
}catch(Exception err){
    err.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm facing the following error:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.mahout.fpm.pfpgrowth.fpgrowth.FPGrowth.growth(FPGrowth.java:331)
at org.apache.mahout.fpm.pfpgrowth.fpgrowth.FPGrowth.fpGrowth(FPGrowth.java:211)
at org.apache.mahout.fpm.pfpgrowth.fpgrowth.FPGrowth.generateTopKFrequentPatterns(FPGrowth.java:302)
at org.apache.mahout.fpm.pfpgrowth.fpgrowth.FPGrowth.generateTopKFrequentPatterns(FPGrowth.java:174)
at myProgram.main(myProgram.java:96)
```

How to interpret this? Is this because of writer set to null? Please help.

Regards,
psun

Answer (score 0):

The error is because I wasn't calling the method generateTopKFrequentPatterns() correctly. Once I modified the call, there is no error.